Add multiple data entries within one column
I need help with adding multiple entries into a single column in Excel, where each column represents a day of the week (e.g., Monday). My goal is to input multiple data entries for a specific day and perform calculations based on those entries within the same column.
I’ve sketched an example of what I’m trying to achieve in Excel
,
but I’m unsure if this is possible or how to go about it. I’ve tried searching online, but I think I’m not using the right terms, so I haven’t found any helpful information yet.
If anyone understands what I’m trying to do or can point me toward resources or guidance on how to solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Do the things in row 11 of your screenshot represent scroll bars? If so, then excel does not support sheets-within-sheets. There are better ways to store and display that kind of data, but we would need more information about what you're doing

I suspect you're taking the wrong approach - keep the columns seperate, and combine them in calculations
This 'feels' a little too simple but just use =SUM(B3:C10) Copy and pasting it to E13 will do it for the next day and so on. Basically 'lists' of cells should work.
Kind of like this

I think this would work for any standard function.
